# What is the normal vector of a 2d image of the top of a tilted cube

Tags: geometry

I am imaging a falling cube and want to know the normal vector of the top of a cube (painted), I have a 2d image of the tilted cube’s top with the coordinates (x and y) of all the corners and the area. Is there a way I can use this 2d projection of the tilted surface, knowing it is a cube, to find the normal vector of the top surface (and so the angle of the cube)

Now I only image the red part of this example;
https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/brioche/uploads/w9yEtjOwy0-cc4.svg?width=300

Comment: Is the side length of the cube known to you ?

Comment: The original length, that is the length of a side if the top would face the viewer, yes. Sadly I cannot add a photo yet because I am a new user :(

Comment: Right now I only image the red part of this example; https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/brioche/uploads/w9yEtjOwy0-cc4.svg?width=300

Comment: If the image you are looking at is an orthogonal projection and you really see only the red face and do not see any of the other parts of the cube, you cannot tell whether the rest of the cube is above or below the red face. If it's in perspective then you can (in principle) tell which corner of the square is closest to the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the four image points $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$ in the $xy$ plane (the plane of the image) arranged in counterclockwise direction (so that $P_1 P_3$ and $P_2 P_4$ are the two diagonals.

Now attach a 3D coordinate frame having its $x$ and $y$ axes aligned with the $x$ and $y$ axes of the image, while the $z$ axis is pointing out of the image plane, and its origin at $P_1$.  If $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, Q_4$ are the actual points in $3$D space, then

$Q_1 = (0, 0, 0) $

$Q_2 = ( P_{2x} - P_{1x} , P_{2y} - P_{1y} , z_2 ) = (x_2, y_2, z_2) $

and (skipping $Q_3$) we have

$Q_4 = (P_{4x} - P_{1x}, P_{4y} - P_{1y}, z_4 )=(x_4, y_4, z_4)$

The only unknowns here are $z_2$ and $z_4$ and we can write two equations relating them, and they are,

1. The length $Q_2$ is equal to the length of $Q_4$

which means that

$ x_2^2 + y_2^2 + z_2^2 = x_4^2 + y_4^2 + z_4^2 $

2. The dot product between $Q_2$ and $Q_4$ is zero, hence,

$ x_2 x_4 + y_2 y_4 + z_2 z_4 = 0 $

These are two quadratic equations in the two unknowns ($z_2$ and $z_4$).  From the second equation, we have

$ z_4 = \dfrac{K}{z_2} \hspace{36pt} \text{where} \hspace{36pt} K = - (x_2 x_4 + y_2 y_4 ) $

Substitute this into the first equation, which can be written as,

$ c_2 + z_2^2 = c_4 + z_4^2 $

where $c_2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2 , c_4 = x_4^2 + y_4^2 $

Hence,

$ c_2 + z_2^2 = c_4 + \dfrac{K^2}{z_2^2} $

Multiplying through by $z_2^2$

$ (c_2 - c_4) z_2^2 + (z_2^2)^2 = K^2 $

which is a simple quadratic equation in $z_2^2 $

If $u = z_2^2$ then,

$ u^2 + (c_2 - c_4) u - K^2 = 0$

Which has only one positive solution.  The positive solution corresponds to two possible values of $z_2$ (the second being the negative of the first), and from the second original equation we obtain a single unique value of $z_4$ for each of the solutions of $z_2$.  Thus there are two possible orientations of the sides of the top face of the cube.

Finally, the normal to the top cube face is along the cross product of $Q_2$ and $Q_4$, and will thus have two possible normals.